# NSXMLParser vs TouchXML/KissXML frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, xml

What is the advantage of using these different frameworks (TouchXML, KissXML, etc) as compare to NSXMLParser?

**Update:** I think there are some other questions which had indirectly asked the same question, so i believe it will be repeat. So i am posting the urls of those questions here. Though i asked the question with some other things in mind but it's ok.

[XML Parsing in Cocoa Touch/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773651/xml-parsing-in-cocoa-touch-iphone)

[iPhone Development - XMLParser vs. libxml2 vs. TouchXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406811/iphone-development-xmlparser-vs-libxml2-vs-touchxml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [blog post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) with comparison of different XML parsers available for iPhone platform