# XML Parsing without Soap message

Tags: xml, ios4, xml-parsing

How to Parse XML from live URL without any soap message.

```
< stores >
< store value="abc" >XYZ< /store >
< store value="pqr" >SAM< /store >
< store value="ZZZ" >ALG< /store >
< /stores >
```

And how to get the value i.e. "abc", "pqr", "ZZZ" from the XML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you're talking about, but this answer might help you: [XML Parsing in Cocoa Touch/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773651/xml-parsing-in-cocoa-touch-iphone).
Also, to actually get the XML from the server, [check out the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)

There's even a [video tutorial about XML parsing on iOS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iKkbi3d35Y)

Comment: Actually i am getting data in these format and i want to store value like abc, pqr, ZZZ, etc. as well as XYZ, SAM, ALG accordingly. But in iphone parsing method i can not get value field in tag.

Comment: TMXML does this: http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Extracting_attributes.html