# Cocoa Touch: parsing XML, should I use NSXMLParser or a Dom parser?

Tags: xml, ios, cocoa-touch, parsing

I need to parse a XML file storing events. I just need to process events with ending date later than actual date, so no many of them will used in the app.

The application will need to sort then before displaying, and then the user will resort and filter the results in a UITableView.

By now I just parse the data with NSXMLParser and load it into a NSMutableArray of Events. Then I can reorder the array or select a subset of it to acomadate to user needs.

What are the benefits of using a Dom parser and building an in-memory representation of the document? how is this representation implemented? is the sorting and filtering faster? does it save memory? can it be configured so only events with some condition are parsed? can it be configured to include needed elements from each event and not all of them?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773651/xml-parsing-in-cocoa-touch-iphone

Comment: "does it -- using a Dom parser -- save memory?". Actually, it can consume a considerable amount of memory, especially if the document is large. An event-driven parser such as `NSXMLParser` consumes much less memory.